# Evaluate expression `3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6`

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4

Consider this expression `3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6`.

[DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=3%20%2B%202%20%2B%201%20-%205%20%2B%204%20%25%202%20-%201%20%2F%204%20%2B%206) evaluates it to `6.75` (as does Google).

Python 2 evaluates it to 7:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6
7
>>> ^D
```

Python 3 evaluates it to 6.75:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr  9 2014, 11:51:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1 / 4 + 6)
6.75
>>>`enter code here`
```

Why does Python 2 evaluate to 7 and Python 3 evaluate to 6.75?

How does Python arrive at the result?

Comment: in python2 / does integer division by default, in python3 it's floating point division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In py2, 1/4->0 for integers, in py3 1/4->0.25. You can use explicit true division in py2

```
3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1. / 4 + 6  # note the decimal point
```

or you can do a

```
from __future__ import division
```

to use the py3 behaviour.

Comment: Could you perhaps add how one can "use explicit true division"?

Comment: Either have a real number (as the answer below), or use numpy.true_divide(1,4) (this is overkill). Note that the operator // does the opposite and produces a whole number, 7.//2.->3.

Comment: Yes, *I* know that, I'm suggesting you *edit the question* to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Integer division in Python 2.x truncates.

Python did not forget how to do math, you just need to give it more instructions sometimes. If you make a simple change to the expression

print 3 + 2 + 1 - 5 + 4 % 2 - 1.00 / 4 + 6

You should get your 6.75